# Float64 to string

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

In C++, how can I convert a data of type float64 to a string without losing any of the data in float64? I need it to not only be converted to a string, but add a string to either side of the number and then sent to be written in a file.

Code:

```
string cycle("---NEW CYCLE ");
cycle+=//convert float64 to string and add to cycle
cycle+= "---\r\n";
writeText(cycle.c_str()); //writes string to txt file
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is a float64? Standard C++ has no type of that name.

Comment: custom type. can be treated as a float.

Comment: It sounds like it would lose some data when converting to float though... in that case you would need to write your own functionality to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sprintf`. See documentation here [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

As an example it would be something like:

```
char str[30];
float flt = 2.4567F;
sprintf(str, "%.4g", flt );
```

Also I would use `string::append` to add the string. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)  .

**UPDATE**

Updated code according to comment.

Comment: `str` can be statically allocated: `char str[20]` and it's actually advisable to prefer this to dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use [`string::operator+=`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) as used in the question?

Comment: No specific reason - I just tend to use append since you have some more options. In this particular case it doesn't matter but like I said I just liek to use...

Comment: Although you'll need rather more than 4 decimal places to represent a general 64-bit floating point value without losing any of the data.

Answer (score 3):

The [usual way](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.1) of converting numbers to `std::string`s is to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

```
std::string stringify(float value)
{
     std::ostringstream oss;
     oss << value;
     return oss.str();
}

    // [...]
    cycle += stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` to format the string.